# Does anybody know how to find the dual of the following (Boolean Algebra)? p*(q+r')

Tags: boolean, truthtable

Does anybody know how to find the dual of the following (`Boolean Algebra`)?

```
p*(q+r')
```

Where `*` stands for `AND`, `+` stands for `OR`, and `'` stands for `NOT`.

I have the following, but it is incorrect:

```
p + (qr')
```

Answer (score 0):

not a and not b => not (a or b) 
Here a = p', b = (q+r')' = (q'r). Hence p*(q+r') = (p'+q'r)'

Comment: i believe that's incorrect .. i tried it , but it returned incorrect. thank you though!